# How to set text color in QLineEdit when background image is set for QlineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QLineEdit` and i have set an image to `QStackedWidget`. Now i want to change the font color of Texts which is in `QLineEdit`. How to do it?

```
QLineEdit *line1 = new QLineEdit("Hello");
QStackedWidget *stack1 = new QStackedWidget();
stack1->addWidget(line1);
stack1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(black.gif);");
```

I tried writing `foreground-color` and `foreground` in `setStyleSheet.` But its not work for me.

Comment: did you try just color: white; ?

Comment: ya i tried white color too

Comment: You shoud use qss property `color` (not foreground-color)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, this can be achieved by setting the *color* stylesheet property, so no foreground-color or something like that. So this should do it:

```
QLineEdit *line1 = new QLineEdit("Hello");
QStackedWidget *stack1 = new QStackedWidget();
stack1->addWidget(line1);
stack1->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(black.gif); color: #FFFFFF");
```

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me :

```
    QPalette *palette = new QPalette();
palette->setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::red);
line->setPalette(*palette);
```

Comment: I believe this is a memory leak. `setPallete` takes a `const &` which is usually a sign that function makes a copy and leaves it to you. You should either declare `QPalette` as value (not pointer) or call delete in the end.